# How do I generate a trimap from a binary mask?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm trying to implement this paper right now:

[Automatic Skin and Hair Masking Using Convolutional Neural Networks](https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~siqin/papers/ICME.pdf)

I've gotten the FCN and CRF part working, and I found the code to generate the alpha mask once I have the trimap.

[image: Diagram from Paper]

I'm stuck on the part between (c) and (d), though.

How do I generate a trimap given the binary mask? The paper says:

> We apply morphological operators on the binary segmentation
>   mask for hair and skin, obtaining a trimap that indicates
>   foreground (hair/skin), background and unknown pixels. In
>   order to deal with segmentation inaccuracies, and to best capture
>   the appearance variance of both foreground and background,
>   we first erode the binary mask with a small kernel,
>   then extract the skeleton pixels as part of foreground constrain
>   pixels. We also erode the binary mask with a larger kernel to
>   get more foreground constrain pixels. The final foreground
>   constrain pixels is the union of the two parts. If we only keep
>   the second part then some thin hair regions will be gone after
>   erosion with a large kernel. If a pixel is outside the dilated
>   mask then we take it as background constrain pixel. All other
>   pixels as marked as unknown, see figure 2 (d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV supports morphological operations.
Please see [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) explaining how to use [`erode`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?#erode) and [`dilate`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?#dilate) functions.

Comment: Thank you - I used those functions and the more detailed explanation here ([Real-Time and Temporal-Coherent Foreground Extraction With Commodity RGBD Camera](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270280273_Real-Time_and_Temporal-Coherent_Foreground_Extraction_With_Commodity_RGBD_Camera)) to solve the problem.